# Options to get parents over age 55 health insurance coverage in Germany

Tags: germany, health-insurance, immigration, german-citizens

I'm a German national. My mother is German, too but my father is a non-EU national. Both of my parents are older than 55.

I'm now thinking of moving to Germany, and some websites claim if I join the public healthcare system, and if my parents don't work, and if we live at the same address, my parents would be covered by my insurance even if they are above 55.

However I haven't been able to get definite confirmation and some other websites claim that this is not the case and there is no way to get coverage by public healthcare if one is above 55 and wasn't covered by the public healthcare system in the past 5 years.

Does someone have a reliable source that can clarify this point?

Comment: Are your parents retired? Do they presently live in Germany? Have they ever been insured in Germany? Are you currently an employed or self-employed and what would your status in Germany be?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean the family health insurance ([Familienversicherung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familienversicherung)) but it woudn't cover your parents. Your insurance covers (under certain qualifications) you, your wife/husband and children, but not your parents.